# dynamic html content, php aspect ratio

Tags: php, html

So I am making a website and a part of it has where users can make a post and put an image.  When a user uploads the photo I want it to resize it smaller to fit the post size. The problem is some users will be uploading in landscape and others in portrait.  I also won't know the aspect ratio(3:4, 16:9).  How can I go about setting my website up for this?  I know how to resize images but should I resize only the width and keep the height in ratio? and how can I set up my dynamic html?

So here is something similar to what I am doing...http://fiverr.com/.

They have a similar post set-up.  When I mess with their images width all it does is stretch it in place.  Also it seems like they have no pictures that are in portrait view.  can someone explain this because i doubt NOONE uploaded a portrait image

Answer (score 0):

```
            old_height
new_height= ---------- * new_width
            old_width

          =    aspect  * new_width
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare the image's aspect ratio with your viewport's before deciding whether to resize by width or height.

If your image display area is `viewport_w` x `viewport_h` and uploaded image is `w` x `h`, then (pseudo-code):

```
viewport_aspect_ratio = viewport_w / viewport_h;
image_aspect_ratio = w / h;

if (image_aspect_ratio > viewport_aspect_ratio) {
    // image aspect ratio is wider than our viewport
    // resize to fit viewport width
    new_w = viewport_w;
    new_h = image_h * viewport_w / image_w;
} else {
    // image aspect ratio is taller than our viewport
    // resize to fit viewport height
    new_w = image_w * viewport_h / image_h;
    new_h = viewport_h;
}

// resize image to new_w x new_h
```